# Magento add to cart object doesn't contain custom options

Tags: magento

I'm using SCP with success, I don't think the problem is there. Basically I've got an observer that looks for the "Add to cart" event and goes from there. Here's my observer method:

```
public function catalogProductLoadAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        // set the additional options on the product
        $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
        if ($action->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add') {
            // assuming you are posting your custom form values in an array called extra_options...
            if ($options = $action->getRequest()->getParam('extra_options')) {
                $product = $observer->getProduct();

                // add to the additional options array
                    $additionalOptions = array();
                if ($additionalOption = $product->getCustomOption('additional_options')) {
                    $additionalOptions = (array)unserialize($additionalOption->getValue());
                }

                foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
                    $additionalOptions[] = array(
                        'label' => $key,
                        'value' => $value,
                        'value' => $value,
                    );
                }
                // add the additional options array with the option code additional_options
                $observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));
            }
        }
    }
```

All looks well and functions just fine. I've dropped in some `Zend_Debug::dump` statements at various points and have found where I think the issue is. `$product` doesn't contain any custom options, or at least doesn't appear to! I've done `Zend_Debug::dump($product);` and this gives me the following: https://gist.github.com/720a111bc299501726d7 The important thing to see here is that the product object shown is a child product of the configurable. ALL child products have custom options (I just had to set them to get to this stage!).

In the cart page the custom options are displayed correctly, as I've just set them. So why at this midpoint when I do `Zend_Debug::dump($product);` just before the `foreach` does the above gist not show any custom options, specifically line 9. My observer fails to do it's job because $additionalOptions ends up being blank, just displays as `array {}`. As such the `foreach` doesn't fire and the script falls over. So why are no custom options shown in the gist, yet they ARE there as they show on the product page AND they show after this script executes on the cart page?

To further "prove" this, I'm getting an Invalid argument for foreach() as a result.